# iOS SpriteKit overlapping SKSpriteNodes / images

Tags: ios, image, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am a beginner and putting together a SpriteKit game in Swift, iOS Xcode. GameViewController passes the value **name: String** to GameScene. GameScene updates two images/SKSpriteNodes named **apple.png** and **orange.png**. The two images/SKSpriteNodes take approx the same position so they should not overlapp. But after several updates they are all overlapped. I have a vague idea that I am creating too many instances and not actually *updating* but unfortunately this is the end of my knowledge.

How do I stop images overlapping at every update? Thank you for helping.

```
func updateName(name: String) {  // name:String is passed from gameViewController
 var XYZ = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "\(name).png")
 if (name == "apple") {
     XYZ.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(...)
     XYZ.position = CGPoint(...)
     XYZ.setScale(...)
     self.addChild(XYZ)
     // animation of apple
 } else if (name == "orange") {
     XYZ.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(another set of ...)
     XYZ.position = CGPoint(another set of ...)
     XYZ.setScale(snother set of ...)
     self.addChild(XYZ)
     // animation of orange
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific with what you are looking for

Comment: What method is this code from? When does the method get called?

Comment: @robmayoff  The method is from Swift - see edited question. func updateName(name: String) get called when "apple" and "orange" need update. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding a child each time on top of one another, take the existing spriteNode and just update the texture (when you declare your sprite make sure to set the `name` property so you could access them). Your function will look like this:

```
func updateName(name: String) {  // name:String is passed from gameViewController
 var XYZ: SKSpriteNode = self.childNodeWithName("\(name)") as SKSpriteNode
 if (name == "apple") {
     XYZ.texture = //set texture however you'd like
     // animation of apple
 } else if (name == "orange") {
     XYZ.texture = //set texture however you'd like
     // animation of orange
 }
 }
```

This way you aren't creating more and more XYZ sprites each time, but rather getting the same spriteNode according to its name to handle your animation. Also, if you have several of these sprites at one time with the same name, you should instead pass the sprite itself into the function to make sure you have the correct instance.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of GameScene I declared XYZ like this

```
    XYZ = SKSpriteNode()
```

Inside the function, the line

```
    var XYZ: SKSpriteNode = self.childNodeWithName("\(name)") as SKSpriteNode
```

returns nil although

```
    println("\(name)")
```

returns the correct name. And does setting the 'name' property mean adding the following line?

```
    name.name = "\(name)"
```

Comment: its the XYZ's name property so its going to be set as `XYZ.name = "\(name)"`

Comment: and are you adding the XYZ as a child of self?